# Quarkus: automatically generate CRUD for Graphql endpoint

Tags: java, graphql, quarkus

I'd like to build some website using heavily CRUD operations (like most websites I guess). I saw that Quarkus provides a way to automatically generate CRUD operations for REST endpoints as shown [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/soa-cloud/quarkus/how-to-generate-jax-rs-crud-application-in-quarkus-using-panache/) (based on PanacheRepositoryResource).

However, I'd love to use a Graphql endpoint instead of REST. Any idea how to automatically generate CRUD opertaions for Graphql in Quarkus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not supported with GraphQL right now. There is an open feature request for it: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/20434 - feel free to watch it or chime in there.

Comment: Thanks! Hope to see this solved soon. Is it possible in the meantime to fake this by writing a generic code once that would automatically create CRUD operations for me?

Comment: Hmm yeah I could perhaps imagine an abstract class like `GraphQLRepository<T>` that contains methods for CRUD operations on type `T` and then the user would create their class that extends it and has `@GraphQLApi` on it. If you're targeting to use this with Panache then `T` would extend `PanacheEntity`. This is a bit of a rough idea but it might work. In the proper Quarkus implementation, it will probably use bytecode generation to make it more generic.